# Notification and achievement dialogs close themselves automatically on login/join page

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the login/join page, the notification and achievement dialogs close themselves immediately after opening. See the following screen capture:

[image]

(Safari 11.0.3 on macOS 10.13.3)

Comment: I've seen this bug too. It is very intermittent and clears up on it's own. I'll ping the dev who most recently work on this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because you're currently in the Stack Overflow for Teams beta and your requests are routed slightly differently to allow access to the data secured within the teams that you are a member of.

It's now fixed! Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Thanks! I have no way to verify it now that I've signed up, of course, but I trust you know what you're doing.